# Reading empty values in "for" command in a windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, null, for-loop, cmd

I have a question with the "for" batch command in windows.

I have a file called keys.txt which contains this line..

> key,value,x86,windows7

I want to parse this line and store the 4 comma seperated variables in 4 variables. I accomplish that by the following windows batch script.

```
 for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=," %%i
 in (keys.txt) do (

    echo first is %%i

    echo second is %%j

    echo third is %%k

    echo fourth is %%l

    echo rest is %%m

    echo -------------  

 )
```

However, when i modify the keys.txt to

> key,value,,windows7

The third variable is printed as windows7. I would expect the 3rd variable to be empty and the 4th variable to be windows7. If i give a space between the 2 comma's like this

> key,value, ,windows7

Then it prints the 3rd variable as empty and the 4th variable as Windows7.

Anyone knows how i can make the earlier case (i.e the one without the space) also to work correctly?

Comment: Why use batch to parse files? Do you have other options? like using a real file parser (language) ? If you can't download and use stuff, you can use vbscript, which is better at doing such jobs.

Comment: Actually, there is a lot of code written using batch scripts, so it would be a huge task to migrate the whole thing to vbs. However, i found another alternative which would be to write a vbs file that would create a file with a list of set var=value lines and then call this batch file from the parent batch file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Idea fom [here](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=170)
The script preprocess each line assigning the text #NUL# to each empty slot. You can disregard #NUL# values after that.

```
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%X in (keys.txt) do (
    set "work=%%X"
    :: fill empty fields with "#NUL#" ...
    :: but do it twice, just in case consecutive fields are empty
    for /l %%i in (1,1,2) do set "work=!work:,,=,#NUL#,!"
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=," %%i in ("!work!") do (
echo first is %%i
echo second is %%j
echo third is %%k
echo fourth is %%l
echo rest is %%m
echo -------------  
))
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

`for` is designed to **not preserve** null/empty tokens on some systems, so allocates next next token to the placeholder (as long as it's also not null/empty). This also happens when printing text with leading space or blank lines on some versions of Windows™.
To work around this, preprocess the data and fill some value in empty data eg. space (as you've experimented) to preserve all tokens.

```
for /f "delims=" %a in (test.1) do set data=%a& set data=!data:,=","!& for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %i in ("!data!") do set a=%i-%j-%k-%l& echo !a:"=!
```

The above code preprocesses data similar to CSV format, which also works with data containing spaces within same 'cell'.
eg. output: `key-value--windows 7`

If your data contains the delimiter `,` and you want it preserved as part of data, then change the delimiter in the `for` or escape it during preprocessing.

*Update (a practical application for mass processing):*
With this method you can also autofill (common)data eg. if you're processing multiple files and file names are to be read from a template file, then instead of typing file names on command prompt for every file to be processed, you can create a template file and read file names from it.

If most of them have a common extension eg. `.txt`, then just type `,,` (blank data) instead of typing .txt everytime, like so:

```
file1,,
file 2,,
file 3la,,
different file,.pdf
```

Then in your code, the blank spaces `,,` will be prefilled with `.txt` (saving time creating the template file).

Here's the code for preprocessing file names before being fed to main process code:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in (test.1) do set data=%a& set data=!data:,=","!& for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %i in ("!data!") do (
REM replace empty cells with ".txt"
echo %j | find "." >nul && (set j=%j) || set j=.txt
set data=%i!j! & echo !data:"=!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For it to work with tab -separated values I did the following, as a modification to Dr. belisarius' answer:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=<TAB>" %%X in (keys.txt) do (
  set "work=%%X"
  for /l %%i in (1,1,3) do set "work=!work:<TAB><TAB>=<TAB>#NUL#<TAB>!"
  for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=<TAB>" %%i in ("!work!") do (
echo first is %%i
echo second is %%j
echo third is %%k
echo fourth is %%l
echo rest is %%m
echo -------------  
))
pause >nul
```

, with <tab> being replaced by the real tab -value